# Remove item from binary file

Tags: c#, file, binary

What's the best and the fastest method to remove an item from a binary file?
I have a binary file and I know that I need to remove B number of bytes from a position A, how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Read the first A bytes, copy them into a temp file, skip B bytes, and continue copying the rest into the temp file.  When done, move it on top of the original.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider working in batches to prevent allocation on the LOH but that depends on the size of your file and the frequency in which you call this logic.

```
        long skipIndex = 100;
        int skipLength = 40;

        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open("file.dat", FileMode.Open))
        {
            int bufferSize;
            checked 
            { 
                bufferSize = (int)(fileStream.Length - (skipLength + skipIndex)); 
            }
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read all data after
            fileStream.Position = skipIndex + skipLength;
            fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            // write to displacement
            fileStream.Position = skipIndex;
            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            fileStream.SetLength(fileStream.Position); // trim the file
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends... There are a few ways to do this, depending on your requirements.

The basic solution is to read chunks of data from the source file into a target file, skipping over the bits that must be removed (is it always only one segment to remove, or multiple segments?). After you're done, delete the original file and rename the temp file to the original's name.

Things to keep in mind here are that you should tend towards larger chunks rather than smaller. The size of your files will determine a suitable value. 1MB is a good 'default'.

The simple approach assumes that deleting and renaming a new file is not a problem. If you have specific permissions attached to the file, or used NTFS streams or some-such, this approach won't work.

In that case, make a copy of the original file. Then, skip to the first byte after the segment to ignore in the copied file, skip to the start of the segment in the source file, and transfer bytes from copy to original. If you're using Streams, you'll want to call Stream.SetLength to truncate the original to the correct size

Comment: Whats wrong with just moving chunks of data around within the original file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just rewrite the original file, and remove a sequence from it the best way is to "rearrange" the file.
The idea is:

```
for i = A+1 to file.length - B
    file[i] = file[i+B]
```

For better performance it's best to read and write in chunks and not single bytes. Test with different chunk sizes to see what best for your target system.